# Как сделать что бы функция не выполнялась быстрее чем 2s?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день есть такая функция

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  });
```

После того как загрузится Dom вывести console.log. Вопрос у меня в другом. Как сделать что бы console.log не выполнялся раньше чем за 2s. К примеру если DOM загрузится за 5 секунд( теоретически ) то выполнить console.log после его выполнение. А если он загрузится за 0.5s пусть console.log не выполнится пока не пройдет 2s

Comment: использовать `setTimeout`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  console.log( 'Прошло ' + performance.now() + ' миллисекунд.' );

  var timeout = 5000 - performance.now(); // Если будет отрицательным - выполнится сразу.
  // 5000 ( 5 секунд ) для демо. У вас это будет 2000

  setTimeout( function(){
    console.log( 'И еще ' + timeout );
  }, timeout);
});
```